# What are the "appop" and "development" protection flags used for?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I was writing some test code to verify the type and scope of the permissions that our apps request and I noticed two new protection levels were recently added to Android.

According to the [official Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html), the `<permission>` element in AndroidManifest.xml accepts one of the following four values:

> android:protectionLevel=["normal" | "dangerous" | "signature" | "signatureOrSystem"]

but I noticed that the `PermissionInfo` class (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#PROTECTION_FLAG_DEVELOPMENT)) has flags for a total of six protection levels. It seems that these two levels were added in SDK 16 and 21, respectively, but they don't appear to be documented:

```
int PROTECTION_FLAG_DEVELOPMENT = 0x20
int PROTECTION_FLAG_APPOP       = 0x40
```

I was wondering what the different between these protection levels and the ones that can be defined in the manifest and if/when should they be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `appop` permission is nothing but a reminiscence of the App Ops tool that Google introduced back in Android 4.3 and has been removed ever since. In theory, permissions with the `appop` flag could be toggled by the user during testing to verify how the app would behave when certain software or hardware features were enabled or disabled.

This is the actual description of App Ops given by Google engineers:

> For example, it is used now for the per-app notification control, for keeping track of when location was accessed in the new location UI, for some aspects of the new current SMS app control, etc.

Here's a link to the full post: https://plus.google.com/+DannyHolyoake/posts/FkfBxA5i3iG

Answer (score 6):

The `development` flag (`0x20`):

> Additional flag from base permission type: this permission can also
>   (optionally) be granted to development applications.

And the `appop` flag (`0x40`):

> Additional flag from base permission type: this permission is closely
>   associated with an app op for controlling access.

Here is the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

The `development` permission, or something similar, is usually used in situations where certain permissions are required for development/debugging purposes but not for release purposes. For example, let us suppose that you are creating a new application. At first, you deploy a release candidate version of the application to a select group of people/testers. You could use the `development` permissions level to enable features that might be useful for initial testing and results gathering, such as GPS to see the location of your testing group and storage/network capabilities to store and email logs for analysis. Once you are ready for a general release, you remove this permission, since the collection of such data is either not needed anymore or, more likely, not really possible for a larger group of people (i.e. privacy concerns, etc.).

As far as the `appop` permission goes, I am not quite sure...

Comment: Thanks Willis! Any idea of what they mean with "development applications" or "an app op for controlling access"?

Answer (score 1):

`GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS` is granted to shell application. It allows the shell user to grant development permissions during runtime. This is done with 
`pm grant` and `pm revoke` commands.

You can check `frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml` to see which permissions that are usually granted only to signature or system apps can be granted to normal applications by shell.